# Unhandled exception on Android after turn off and then turn on internet connection

Tags: android, blazor, maui

I'm making an App with MAUI Blazor with a synchronization function to upload information stored locally on the mobile to the database but when i turn off and the turn on my internet connection i got an unhandled exception.

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'ObjectDisposed_StreamClosed'

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception
0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12,5 
0x23 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLII_I at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:265,26    
0xB in System.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException_StreamClosed
0x9 in System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureNotClosed
0x9 in System.IO.MemoryStream.Read
0x9 in Android.Runtime.InputStreamAdapter.Read at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/InputStreamAdapter.cs:38,4
0x23 in Java.IO.InputStream.n_Read_arrayBII at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Java.IO.InputStream.cs:264,4
0xD in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLII_I at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:264,5
```

Any idea about what could be?

I don't know exactly why is referring to a stream.

Comment: do you have any exception handling in your sync function?